# Read SD card image into ListView

Tags: android, listview, hashmap

I managed to use drawable image into my listview, but how can I do the same with image from SD card?

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("KEY_IMAGE", Integer.toString(R.drawable.a)); //change to SD card
map.put("KEY_LINK", "link");
map.put("KEY_NAME", "name");
menuItems.add(map);

String[] from = { "KEY_IMAGE", "KEY_NAME", "KEY_LINK" };
int[] to =  {R.id.imageView_cell, R.id.list_headline,R.id.list_info };

SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), menuItems, R.layout.list_view,from, to);

listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without implementing a custom adapter.

You should implement the [`SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder.html) interface, and invoke [`setViewBinder()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html#setViewBinder%28android.widget.SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder%29) to tell your adapter how to bind the data.

As mentioned by LordRaydenMK, it's good practice to load the images asynchronously (e.g. using [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)), inside your implementation of [`setViewValue()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder.html#setViewValue%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a custom adapter and override the `getView` method. You can find an example [here](http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/) using the best practices for view recycling and View holders.

Loading images, especially in adapters should be done in a background thread so it doesn't slow down the UI.

For background loading you can use a library like [Picasso.](https://github.com/square/picasso)

```
Picasso.with(context).load(new File(...)).into(imageView2);
```